# Define an array in mongodb to contain only unique strings (a set)

Tags: mongodb

I want to define an array in a mongodb document to only contain unique values, is there a way to do this?

So if I added `jon@gmail.com` to the json entry below it wouldn't add the email into the json document

```
{"emails":['jon@gmail.com', 'seth@gmail.com']}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add a new element to the array, instead of using `$push` use `$addToSet`. addToSet will only add the element if the element does not already exist.

```
{ $addToSet: { email: "jon@gmail.com" } }
```

Comment: is it possible to do this with a set of json documents? so the array contains items that have `[ { email: "jon@gmail.com, name: "jon"}, {email: "seth@gmail.com", name: "seth"} ]` and it wouldn't add a new `{ email: "jon@gmail.com, name: "jon"}` to the array?